# remove duplicated element from dictionary and list and sort element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove and order my list of element

```
['elt9', 'elt19', 'elt1', 'elt2', 'elt3','elt9','elt2']
```

and get

```
['elt1', 'elt2', 'elt3', 'elt9', 'elt19']
```

This is all my code:

```
import itertools as it
import re
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

L1 = ['elt1', 'elt2', 'elt3', 'elt4', 'elt5', 'elt6', 'elt9']
L2 = [['elt1','elt11'],['elt2','elt12'],['elt3','elt13'], ['elt4','elt14']]

def generate_combinations(L):    
    L_com = []
    for r in range(1, len(L)+1):
        L_com += list(it.combinations(L, r))           

    all_combination= []
    for i in L_com:
        for j in L2:
            all_combination.append(j+list(i))

    l = sorted(set(all_combination), key = lambda x : int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[0]))
    with open('combinations.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
         for item in l:
             file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_combinations(L1)
```

I had this error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-e0b599cc4158> in <module>()
      1 if __name__ == "__main__":
----> 2     generate_combinations(L1)

<ipython-input-45-81ef5db3553e> in  generate_combinations(L1)
     21 
     22     #sorted(set(all_combination), key=lambda x: int(x[3:]))
---> 23     l = sorted(set(all_combination), key = lambda x : int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[0]))
     24 
     25     with open('combinations.txt', 'w') as file_handler:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Please check if my answer worked for you :)

Comment: but I had this error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: This has nothing to do with dictionary data structure as you mentioned within the question title.

Comment: What is your program trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Use `set` with `sorted`:

```
l = ['elt9', 'elt19', 'elt1', 'elt2', 'elt3','elt9','elt2']
sorted(set(l), key=lambda x: int(x[3:]))

['elt1', 'elt2', 'elt3', 'elt9', 'elt19']
```

Comment: thank you AK47, but I had this error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @noaai The code provided by this answer worked correctly. Could you post the relevant sections of code that produced this error?

Comment: I posted my code, please help me where is the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
l= ['elt9', 'elt19', 'elt1', 'elt2', 'elt3','elt9','elt2']
l = sorted(set(l), key = lambda x : int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[0]))
l
['elt1', 'elt2', 'elt3', 'elt9', 'elt19']
```

This will also work for any number digit number(3, 4 digit number etc) and not just 2. But the caveat is it should only have one number  for it to work. The re.findall finds all the patterns provided to it and returns a list satisfying that pattern. The pattern `\d+` represents one or more integers.

Comment: I had this error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 0):

In variable **all_combination** you have two-dimensional list/array ([['elt1', 'elt11', 'elt1'], ['elt2', 'elt12', 'elt1'], ['elt3', 'elt13', 'elt1'], ['elt4', 'elt14', 'elt1'], ['elt1', 'elt11', 'elt2'], ...)
and with that you are trying to do:

l = sorted(set(**all_combination**), key = lambda x : int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[0]))

that part of the code works with the types of lists you mentioned in your post:

```
L1 = ['elt9', 'elt19', 'elt1', 'elt2', 'elt3','elt9','elt2']
l = sorted(set(L1), key = lambda x : int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[0]))
print (l)
```

result: ['elt1', 'elt2', 'elt3', 'elt9', 'elt19']